In England, what are the potential jurisdictional issues when a company has two domiciles?
The UK is considering introducing a corporate re-domiciliation regime.
Suppose a company is simultaneously incorporated in the UK and another jurisdiction (during a legal transitional period when the company has transferred its place of incorporation to the new UK domicile but has not yet de-registered from the original domicile). As a result, the company has acquired two domiciles for a period of time until the de-registration process is completed.
What potential jurisdictional or conflict of laws issues might arise when a company has two places of incorporation?

I'm not convinced that the notion of a corporation being simultaneously incorporated in two places at once is a legally cognizable possibility. This isn't really consistent with the concept of being incorporated.

@ohwilleke in other words, the scenario described in the question actually concerns two related but legally distinct corporations?

@phoog I'm not sure what to make of this scenario. It isn't clear what would actually be happening. Two distinct corporations would be one possibility.

You’re talking about two seperate corporations
Corporations are governed by national law - they can’t emigrate.
Now, if I want to change where a business is based, say from Australia to the UK, I create a new company in the UK, transfer the assets (including the business) from the Australian company to the UK company, and then deregister the Australian company. I can’t move the Australian company to the UK.
Now, a company (or any other legal person) can operate in multiple jurisdictions and therefore be subject to the laws of multiple jurisdictions.  But it’s only incorporated in one.

...or it handles all operations in other countries by subsidiaries: fully owned companies that deal with all business there and send profits to the parent company abroad

@Trish still two separate corporations
